# Access Report from p:menuitem

Tags: java

Hi I´m new in java and I would like to redirect the `RelatorioAlunoServlet.java` from my `template.xhtml`. The `RelatorioAlunoServlet.java` is a java class.

How can I do this ? In fact I want to call a report made from Jasper Report from primefaces.

```
<p:submenu label="Relatório" icon="ui-icon-pencil">
     <p:menuitem value="Usuário" url="RelatorioAlunoServlet" icon="ui-icon-home"/>
</p:submenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `p:menuitem` can have a actionlistener. Use it like below

```
<p:submenu label="Relatório" icon="ui-icon-pencil">
    <p:menuitem value="Usuário" actionListener="#{RelatorioAlunoServlet.createReport}" icon="ui-icon-home" ajax="false"/>
</p:submenu>
```

So now, you call a `createReport`-method in your bean. the `ajax="false"` is necessary for the jasper-way to get reports to outputstreams.